# QuarkusTest: Inject the correct instance

Tags: java, junit, quarkus

I am using Quarkus for a little project and I got stuck in unit testing my classes using the tools that Quarkus offers.

The problem is, I used the following approach to mock som classes:
https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#mock-support

Mocking my Dao or Service class would be a nice way in my opinion.
However Mocking my classes leads to the effect that when I inject my Service/Dao class that has to be tested, the container for sure injects the Mock implementation.

Is there a way to prevent that and use the real implementation class?

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class ExpenseDaoImpl implements ExpenseDao {

}

@Mock
@ApplicationScoped
public class ExpenseDaoMock implements ExpenseDao {

}

@QuarkusTest
class ExpenseDaoTest {

    @Inject
    private ExpenseDao expenseDao;  //injects the mocked implementation

}
```

Comment: Yes currently "mocking" a class leads to that class being used everywhere. This might change in the future

Comment: well, thanks for the answer. So it would be better then to use something like Mockito or similar

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that would only for unit tests